# How do I test PayPal DoExpressCheckoutPayment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

TL;DR Where do I get the `PAYERID` to pass into the `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` call?

I'm trying to create an automated test suite (my app is in Ruby) for the entire authorize and capture process of ExpressCheckout. I'm already able to test `SetExpressCheckout` which returns the token which I need to set in the URL for where the user will be redirected.

However, I now want to test a call to `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` from when the customers is redirected back to my application. The 3 required fields are:

1. `TOKEN` (which I already have from `SetExpressCheckout`)
2. `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT` (I already have this)
3. `PAYERID` (where do I get this if this is an automated test suite?)

Is it even possible? Are there default values for these for which I can test the `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`? I'll also need help with `DoCapture`.

Comment: `PayerID` should be one of the query string params when the user is redirected back to your web app...

Comment: @EdSF thanks for the comment but what I'm trying to do is create an automated test squite. So I can't recreate the act of logging in and authorizing the payment wherein I will be redirected back. I was hoping there was some kind of default `PAYERID` for testing purposes. Would you know if there is one?

Answer (score 0):

A user's "payer id" is what you get in that param (static/doesn't change) so you could use a sandbox account and obtain the payer_id (for reuse). You could also obtain it via [`GetExpressCheckoutDetails`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) call where it will part of the Response:

`PAYERID` Unique PayPal Customer Account identification number.

Unsure if that gets you anywhere for a "full automated cycle" because if you follow the flow, the "user" (for a particular transaction, let's call that the "token") is identified only after they approve your request...

If/when they approve your request for payment, which is done at Paypal, only then will that "relationship" (token and payer_id) be created (and then redirected to your site, etc.). So you'd be missing the "approval" step (that creates the relationship).

All of this is subject to correction by Paypal folk :)